# Mover slider en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

he intentado mover el slider dependiendo en el elemento del que se hizo clic, pero no lo consigo. Consegui obtener el ancho del item para modificarlo respecto al contenido. Espero que puedan ayudarme, de antemano gracias

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item-category'),
                slider = document.querySelector('.slider')
            items.forEach((item, e) => {
                item.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    console.log(e)
                    let getWidth = item.offsetWidth
                    slider.style.width = getWidth + 'px'
                })
                
            })
```

```css
.category-results {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
}.menu-item-category:nth-child(1), .menu-item-category:nth-child(2) {
 margin-right: 25px;
}.menu-item-category {
 color: #262626;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 text-transform: capitalize;
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: color 300ms ease-in-out;
}.slider {
 position: absolute;
 height: 3px;
 background: red;
 width: 39%;
 bottom: 0;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-results">
       <div class="menu-item-category active">trending</div>
       <div class="menu-item-category">text too loooong</div>
       <div class="menu-item-category">test3</div>
                <div class="slider" style="width: 81px;"></div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código está correcto, sólo falta mover el slider abajo del item del menú. Puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
slider.style.left = item.offsetLeft + 'px';
```

Incluye esa línea debajo de `slider.style.width = getWidth + 'px'` para que el slider se mueva tantos píxeles a la izquierda como el ítem al que le hiciste click.